# Regex : Looking for dots in a sentence except inside braquets

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm looking for a regex to split a java string on "dots" in a sentence except if these dots are between brackets.
This is to say that in this example sentence :

```
word1.word2.word3[word4.word5[word6.word7]].word8
```

I would like to split only the first two ones and the last one (just before "word8").

I managed to get to this regex :

```
\.(?![^\[]*?\])
```

But it's not good enough as it also splits on the dot between words 4 and 5 :-(

Any idea to solve this particuliar case ?

Comment: If the brackets can be nested (which it looks like they can) then regular expressions can't be used to do this; you'd have to use some kind of parser.

Comment: @arshajii : I can't believe regex don't deal with nested elements... Isn't there some kind of negative lookback solution ?

Comment: Java regex does not support recursion. PCRE/Boost/Onigmo does.

Comment: I think you cannot solve your pattern by just **one** regex. It is better to separate your pattern in two or more step

Answer (score 0):

By looking at [PerlMonks discussions](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=547596) I don't think the problem can be solved in Java by a single regex.

If you are okay with using multiple steps, then you could first remove all [pairs of brackets](https://regex101.com/r/b3eMNG/1/) (starting with the innermost) and then split the remaining string by dots:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    String str = "word1.word2.word3[word4.word5[word6.word7]].word8";
    final Pattern BRACKET_PAIR = Pattern.compile("\\[[^\\[\\]]+\\]");

    while (BRACKET_PAIR.matcher(str).find()) {
        str = BRACKET_PAIR.matcher(str).replaceFirst("");
    }

    for (String word: str.split("\\.")) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

Resulting in [the output](http://ideone.com/NZKbjr):

```
word1
word2
word3
word8
```